# Javascript select variable

Tags: javascript, select

I am working on a speed writing application. In that application I want to include the possibility to select different word lists.

My problem is how I can select the variable for the word list.

This is the way it works without a word list selection:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', init);


let messagegameover;
messagegameover = "<span style='color:#ff0000'>Game over!</span>"; // store the string

let messagecorrect;
messagecorrect = "<span style='color:green'>Correct!!</span>";

//**************

const select = document.getElementById("language-select");
const textSpan = document.getElementById("text-span");
const valueSpan = document.getElementById("value-span");

function showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan) {
  const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  if (option) {
    textSpan.textContent = option.text;
    valueSpan.textContent = option.value;
  } else {
    // No option is selected
    textSpan.textContent = "";
    valueSpan.textContent = "";
  }
}

// Show on page load
showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan);

// Hook the `input` event
select.addEventListener("input", () => {
  // Update the contents of the elements
  showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan);
});

//**********************

// Schwierigkeitsgrad
const levels = {
  easy: 5,
  medium: 3,
  hard: 2
}

// Auswahl des Schwierigkeitsgrads
const currentLevel = levels.easy;

// Globale Variablen
let time = currentLevel;
let score = 0;
let isPlaying;

// DOM-Elemente
const wordInput = document.querySelector('#word-input');
const currentWord = document.querySelector('#current-word');
const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('#time');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const seconds = document.querySelector('#seconds');

const wordsdeu = [
  'Hund', 'Katze', 'Maus'
];

const wordseng = [
  'dog', 'cat', 'mouse'
];

// Spielstart
function init() {
  // Zahl in Sekunden anzeigen
  seconds.innerHTML = currentLevel;
  // Lade Wörter aus Array
  showWord(wordseng); //replace wordseng by valueSpan
  // Worteingabe prüfen
  wordInput.addEventListener('input', startMatch);
  // Countdown Sekunden
  setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  // Spielstatus
  setInterval(checkStatus, 50);
}

// Wortgleichzeit prüfen
function startMatch() {
  if (matchWords()) {
    isPlaying = true;
    time = currentLevel + 1;
    showWord(wordseng); //replace wordseng by valueSpan
    wordInput.value = '';
    score++;
  }
  // wenn score <0, dann 0
  if (score === -1) {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
  }

}

// prüfen ob Wörter gleich
function matchWords() {
  if (wordInput.value === currentWord.innerHTML) {
    message.innerHTML = messagecorrect;
    return true;
  } else {
    message.innerHTML = ' ';
    return false;
  }
}



// zufällige Wortanzeige
function showWord(wordseng) { //replace wordseng by valueSpan
  // zufälliges Array für Index
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordseng.length); //replace wordseng by valueSpan
  // zufälliges Wort
  currentWord.innerHTML = wordseng[randIndex]; //replace wordseng by valueSpan
}

// timer
function countdown() {
  // prüfen, ob Zeit abgelaufen
  if (time > 0) {
    // abnehmend
    time--;
  } else if (time === 0) {
    // Spielende
    isPlaying = false;
  }
  // Restzeit
  timeDisplay.innerHTML = time;
}

function checkStatus() {
  if (!isPlaying && time === 0) {
    //message.innerHTML = 'Game Over!!!';
    message.innerHTML = messagegameover;
    score = -1;
  }
}
```

```html
  <label for="language">Choose a language:</label>
  <select name="language" id="language-select" value="wordsdeu">
    <option value="wordseng">English</option>
    <option value="wordsdeu">Deutsch</option>
  </select>

  <p>The following two lines are for testing purposes only</p>
  <p>You selected: <span id="text-span"></span></p>
  <p>You selected the following option: <span id="value-span"></span></p>
  <!-- strange behaviour: does not work if I remove the line before -->

  <br><br>
  <p class="maxtimetext">Max. time to write this word:
    <span class="maxtime" id="seconds"></span> Seconds</p>
  <br>

  <h2 id="current-word">hello</h2>
  <input type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Start typing..." id="word-input" autofocus>
  <h4 class="message" id="message"></h4>
  <br>
  <h3>Time Left: <span class="time-left" id="time">0</span></h3>
  <br>
  <p class="score">Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>
  <br>

  <p>Game over? To restart just type the word!</p>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
```

The following snippet shows my desired code that is apparently faulty:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', init);


let messagegameover;
messagegameover = "<span style='color:#ff0000'>Game over!</span>"; // store the string

let messagecorrect;
messagecorrect = "<span style='color:green'>Correct!!</span>";

//**************

const select = document.getElementById("language-select");
const textSpan = document.getElementById("text-span");
const valueSpan = document.getElementById("value-span");

function showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan) {
  const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  if (option) {
    textSpan.textContent = option.text;
    valueSpan.textContent = option.value;
  } else {
    // No option is selected
    textSpan.textContent = "";
    valueSpan.textContent = "";
  }
}

// Show on page load
showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan);

// Hook the `input` event
select.addEventListener("input", () => {
  // Update the contents of the elements
  showTextAndValue(select, textSpan, valueSpan);
});

//**********************

// Schwierigkeitsgrad
const levels = {
  easy: 5,
  medium: 3,
  hard: 2
}

// Auswahl des Schwierigkeitsgrads
const currentLevel = levels.easy;

// Globale Variablen
let time = currentLevel;
let score = 0;
let isPlaying;

// DOM-Elemente
const wordInput = document.querySelector('#word-input');
const currentWord = document.querySelector('#current-word');
const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('#time');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const seconds = document.querySelector('#seconds');

const wordsdeu = [
  'Hund', 'Katze', 'Maus'
];

const wordseng = [
  'dog', 'cat', 'mouse'
];

// Spielstart
function init() {
  // Zahl in Sekunden anzeigen
  seconds.innerHTML = currentLevel;
  // Lade Wörter aus Array
  showWord(valueSpan); //replace wordseng by valueSpan
  // Worteingabe prüfen
  wordInput.addEventListener('input', startMatch);
  // Countdown Sekunden
  setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  // Spielstatus
  setInterval(checkStatus, 50);
}

// Wortgleichzeit prüfen
function startMatch() {
  if (matchWords()) {
    isPlaying = true;
    time = currentLevel + 1;
    showWord(valueSpan); //replace wordseng by valueSpan
    wordInput.value = '';
    score++;
  }
  // wenn score <0, dann 0
  if (score === -1) {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
  }

}

// prüfen ob Wörter gleich
function matchWords() {
  if (wordInput.value === currentWord.innerHTML) {
    message.innerHTML = messagecorrect;
    return true;
  } else {
    message.innerHTML = ' ';
    return false;
  }
}



// zufällige Wortanzeige
function showWord(valueSpan) { //replace wordseng by valueSpan
  // zufälliges Array für Index
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * valueSpan.length); //replace wordseng by valueSpan
  // zufälliges Wort
  currentWord.innerHTML = valueSpan[randIndex]; //replace wordseng by valueSpan
}

// timer
function countdown() {
  // prüfen, ob Zeit abgelaufen
  if (time > 0) {
    // abnehmend
    time--;
  } else if (time === 0) {
    // Spielende
    isPlaying = false;
  }
  // Restzeit
  timeDisplay.innerHTML = time;
}

function checkStatus() {
  if (!isPlaying && time === 0) {
    //message.innerHTML = 'Game Over!!!';
    message.innerHTML = messagegameover;
    score = -1;
  }
}
```

```html
  <label for="language">Choose a language:</label>
  <select name="language" id="language-select" value="wordsdeu">
    <option value="wordseng">English</option>
    <option value="wordsdeu">Deutsch</option>
  </select>

  <p>The following two lines are for testing purposes only</p>
  <p>You selected: <span id="text-span"></span></p>
  <p>You selected the following option: <span id="value-span"></span></p>
  <!-- strange behaviour: does not work if I remove the line before -->

  <br><br>
  <p class="maxtimetext">Max. time to write this word:
    <span class="maxtime" id="seconds"></span> Seconds</p>
  <br>

  <h2 id="current-word">hello</h2>
  <input type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Start typing..." id="word-input" autofocus>
  <h4 class="message" id="message"></h4>
  <br>
  <h3>Time Left: <span class="time-left" id="time">0</span></h3>
  <br>
  <p class="score">Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>
  <br>
  <p>Game over? To restart just type the word!</p>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
```

What I also observed and may have to do with the problem is that if in the following code I remove the first line, it doesn't show the second line neither, which is what I don't understand:

```
 <p>You selected: <span id="text-span"></span></p> 
 <p>You selected the following option: <span id="value-span"></span></p> <!-- strange behaviour: does not work if I remove the line before -->
```

I put it on JSFiddle for testing:
https://jsfiddle.net/engr58wm/

Comment: Instead of two separate variables `wordsdeu` and `wordseng`, use an _object_ that has two properties by those names, and the actual data arrays stored under those. Then you can easily access the correct list based on your selected option value, via `objectVarName[selectedOptionValue]`

Comment: Makes sense to me. So I changed the variable to
`const words = {
wordsdeu: ['Hund','Katze','Maus'],
wordseng: ['dog','cat','mouse']
}`

But I don't know how to address it. Actually what lacks is my knowledge of syntax, I think.
I just made a new fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/msori58/engr58wm/

`function showWord(words[valueSpan) {` or `currentWord.innerHTML = words[valueSpan][randIndex];` are definitely wrong, but what is the correct syntax?

Comment: You access them via `words.wordsdeu` and `words.wordseng`, which in JavaScript can also be written as `words["wordsdeu"]` and `words["wordseng"]`. And since in the latter syntax, those property names are expressed via text literals now, you can also replace those literals with a _variable_ containing the same string value now. `var whatToAccess = "wordsdeu"; do_something_with( words[whatToAccess] );`

Comment: `function showWord(words[valueSpan])` is wrong. This is the function definition, so you need to use a parameter name that follows the conventions for such identifiers in JavaScript. You can pass a value such as `words[valueSpan]` when you _call_ a function, but in this place here that simply makes no sense at all.

Comment: O.k. corrected that. Still doesn't work. Maybe the same reason why it doesn't show the value of valueSpan when I omit `const textSpan = document.getElementById("text-span");` on the top? See https://jsfiddle.net/engr58wm/

For instance is this correct `currentWord.innerHTML = words[valueSpan][randIndex];` ?
Looks strange to me, but I don't know what the error is. I am quite sure that there is only a tiny thing missing in my code.

Comment: _“but I don't know what the error is”_ - then familiarize yourself with the browser console, that’s where you will see error messages, when something is wrong with your code. Your variable `valueSpan` does not contain a string value, it is the reference to the element with ID `value-span` - and using that to try and access `words[valueSpan]`, makes no sense. You would need to get the text content of that element first of all. But since you probably want to change the content of that element based on the select field, defining the variable as `const` also makes little sense.